# How to authenticate user with Azure AD in dotnet core to work with Power Bi Report

Tags: azure, .net-core, powerbi-embedded

I am creating API in Dotnet Core which get access token and based on that implement with Power BI reports. I have created App registration which is a web app on azure. I want to implement token functionality with `grant_type = password` method.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var result = await client.PostAsync(oauthEndpoint, new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", AppSettings.resourceUrl),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", AppSettings.clientId),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", AppSettings.pbiUsername),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", AppSettings.pbiPassword),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "openid")})
    );

    var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuthResult>(content);
}

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", Appsettings.ClientSecret),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", AppSettings.clientId),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", AppSettings.resourceUrl),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", AppSettings.pbiUsername),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", AppSettings.pbiPassword)
   });
    var tenantName = AppSettings.tenantName;
    accessToken =
        await client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize", content)
           .ContinueWith<string>((response) =>
           {
               AzureAdTokenResponse tokenRes =
               JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AzureAdTokenResponse>(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
         .Result);
               return tokenRes?.AccessToken;
           });
}
```

I want the token to be returned by using the above method.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Then this issue can be closed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint is not correct, you should use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token`. Also, you missed `password` parameter  and duplicated `resource` parameter in the KeyValuePair.

**The request** looks like this:

[image]

**The response**:

[image]

**The code:**(You need to JsonConvert the result)

```
public static string passwordGetToken()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
              {
                          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", ""),
                          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"),
                          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", ""),
                          new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "")

                       });
            var response =
                 client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token", content).Result;

            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
```